# Accessing drop down list- selenium webdriver & java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to write a few test cases for automation testing as a part of practice assignment in selenium webdriver using java.

The java version is 1.6 and selenium webdriver version is 2.39 while firefox browser version is 29.0.1.

I am trying to access the drop down titled CARSIZE in the following link:

http://www.carrentals.com/

I am not able to manipulate it.

I have tried the following code...

```
    driver.get("http:\\www.carrentals.com/");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='carType']")));

    dropdown.selectByValue("carsize-1");
```

With the above code, it seems that I am able to find the element(as no exception is thrown) but not change a value. When I try to change a value by SELECTBYVALUE method, I get an exception saying element not visible. Can someone help me?

The Html code for the above can be seen in firebug and just for information I have also tried using ID and name  instead of XPath for the concerned select box but I get the same exception.

Comment: I just want to add one more point.I have read on google groups that if there exists a hidden element with the same id then you get this exception of element not visible. I checked the  size of the list and it is 1 and hence there is no duplicate element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='cartype']")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Small Cars");
```

**Updated.**

Try this code. It works for me.

```
    String dropdownXpath = "//label[@for='cartype']/following-sibling::div[@role='listbox']";
    WebElement textInDropDown = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(dropdownXpath + "//div[@class='text']"));
    textInDropDown.click();
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(dropdownXpath)).sendKeys("Small Cars");
```

It locates text in dropdown element and then sends value which you want to select.

Comment: I tried the code suggested by you but face the same exception.. I

Comment: Andreyla---The exception I get is org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. This is coming at line where I am setting SelectByVisibleText

Comment: Glad to hear that! Could you please mark your question as answered?